# Fastest way to find if an array contains any member of another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, set, intersection

I'm trying to detect whether a file, read in as a string, is either:

1. Text (of some type of single-byte encoding).
2. A multi-byte encoding, or binary, etc.

I have a "blacklist" array of characters/bytes which [normally will never occur](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/src/encoding.c#L196) in "text":

```
bad_bytes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127]
```

And `my_bytes = File.binread('some_file').bytes`.

I can think of:

- `(my_bytes & bad_bytes).empty?`, and
- `my_bytes == (my_bytes - bad_bytes)`

Both produce the correct result, and my intuition is that the latter might be a little faster. Or, maybe they're exactly equivalent? But both seem rather inefficient to me, at for my purpose. I don't need to actually find the *complete* intersection, or remove *each* instance of the second array from the first - finding *one* common element is sufficient.

Am I missing some method that already exists to do this? Is there a faster technique? If not, which of the above is faster? Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Also, for bonus points: is there a **math**/**computer science**/**fancy** term for what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Also, yes, it has to be done in pure Ruby. I realize in some other language will be loads faster, etc.

Comment: Use the [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) class, or look at the [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem to figure out what's faster. I recommend Fruity as it's easier, but YMMV.

Comment: You should look into the [Linix `file` command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm). It uses an interesting set of fingerprinting techniques ([magic](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_magic.htm)) to determine what a file is. You can easily piggy-back on it using any of the various ways of calling a sub-process in Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan

That's actually **exactly** what I'm doing!
https://github.com/geoff-codes/autoencode/blob/master/lib/autoencode.rb#L32

Basically, I'm just reimplementing the heuristics in `encoding.c` in ruby. Eventually, I might just make it a C extension, but its nice to be able to use it in combination with Ruby iconv, and I like the idea of doing it in pure Ruby for portability's sake.

Comment: I'd just use `popen` to open `file` and take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gentlemen! Start your engines!**

Below is a benchmark comparison of the three answers given to date. My main reason for doing this was to evaluate the relative efficiency of @Stefan's solution, which uses a regex. I had the impression that regex's are often relatively inefficient, but as you can see from the results below, that certainly is not the case here.

@Uri's and my solution show how much improvement is made by converting the array of bad characters to a set, and by reading the file byte by byte.  My apologies, @Uri, if I didn't read the file into an array the way you would have.

I would like to see more benchmarking of SO answers done. It's not difficult or time-consuming, and it can provide useful insights. I find most of the time is preparing the test cases. Notice I've put the methods to be tested in a module, so if another method is to be benchmarked, I need only add that method to the module-I don't have to touch any of the other code.

**Methods compared**

```
module Methods
  require 'set'

  Bad_bytes_pattern = /[\x00-\x06\x0B\x0E-\x1A\x1C-\x1F\x7F]/n
  Bad_bytes = [*0..6, 11, *14..26, *28..31, 127]
  Bad_chars = Bad_bytes.map(&:chr)
  Bad_bytes_set = Set[*Bad_bytes]
  Bad_chars_set = Set[*Bad_chars]

  def stefan(fname)
    File.read(fname)[Bad_bytes_pattern]
  end

  def uri_with_array(fname)
    !File.read(fname).each_char.map(&:ord).none? { |b|
      Bad_bytes.include? b }
  end

  def uri_with_set(fname)
    !File.read(fname).each_char.map(&:ord).none? { |b|
      Bad_bytes_set.include? b }
  end

  def cary(fname)
    f = File.new fname
    f.each_char.any? { |c| Bad_chars_set.include?(c) }
  end
end
```

**Include the module**

```
include Methods
@methods = Methods.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:stefan, :uri_with_array, :uri_with_set, :cary]
```

**Create test files**

```
def make_test_files(prefix, nbr_files, file_size, prob_bad_byte)
  nbr_bad_bytes = Bad_bytes.size
  nbr_files.times.with_object([]) do |i, fnames|
    str = 'x'*file_size
    str[rand(file_size)] = Bad_chars[rand(nbr_bad_bytes)] if
      rand < prob_bad_byte
    fname = "#{prefix}.#{i}"
    File.write(fname, str)
    fnames << fname
  end
end

N = 50
M = 100_000
Prob_bad_byte = 0.5

@test_files = make_test_files('test', N, M, Prob_bad_byte)
```

**Create a helper method**

Invoke method `m` to process all test files and return true/false array, true if a bad byte is found in a given file:

```
def compute(m)
  @test_files.each_with_object([]) { |fname,arr|
    arr << (send(m, fname) ? true : false) }
end
```

**Write test header**

```
puts "#{N} files of size #{M}.\n" +
  "Each file contains zero or one bad characters, the probability of the " +
  "latter being #{Prob_bad_byte}. If a bad character is present, it is at " +
  "a random location in the file.\n\n"
```

**Confirm all methods being tested return the same values for the test data**

```
unless @methods.map { |m| compute(m) }.uniq.size == 1
  print "Not all methods agree"
  exit
end
```

**Write the benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

@indent = methods.map { |m| m.to_s.size }.max

Benchmark.bm(@indent) do |bm|
  @methods.each do |m|
    bm.report m.to_s do
      compute(m)
    end
  end
end
```

**Clean up after**

```
@test_files.each { |fname| File.delete fname }
```

**Results for hand-coded test parameters**

*50 files of size 10000.
Each file contains zero or one bad characters, the probability of the latter being 0.5. If a bad character is present, it is at a random location in the file.*

```
                                 user     system      total        real
stefan                       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003874)
uri_with_array               0.560000   0.000000   0.560000 (  0.565312)
uri_with_set                 0.170000   0.010000   0.180000 (  0.173694)
cary                         0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.100730)
```

*50 files of size 100000.
Each file contains zero or one bad characters, the probability of the latter being 0.5. If a bad character is present, it is at a random location in the file.*

```
                                 user     system      total        real
stefan                       0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.027062)
uri_with_array               5.340000   0.040000   5.380000 (  5.387314)
uri_with_set                 1.640000   0.040000   1.680000 (  1.683844)
cary                         0.930000   0.010000   0.940000 (  0.929722)
```

*50 files of size 100000.
Each file contains zero or one bad characters, the probability of the latter being 1.0. If a bad character is present, it is at a random location in the file.*

```
                                 user     system      total        real
stefan                       0.020000   0.010000   0.030000 (  0.022462)
uri_with_array               4.410000   0.030000   4.440000 (  4.447397)
uri_with_set                 1.520000   0.040000   1.560000 (  1.560788)
cary                         0.740000   0.010000   0.750000 (  0.747580)
```

Comment: Wow. Well that answer's that! @Stefan, I hope you'll forgive me for not "choosing" your answer; obviously it _is_ the right answer.

Cary, thank you for taking the time to do this. I'm something of an intermediate-level Rubyist, and I didn't know how to approach this at all. Hence why I asked the question, and this type of answer is exactly why SO still rocks. Do you mind if I use this code in the gem I'm building?

Comment: I would have chosen @Stefan's answer, and you did promise: "if it is indeed faster, I'll mark this the right answer". I wouldn't be the least bit disappointed if you decide to change your selection.  By all means, use whatever you like for the gem.

Comment: Regexp are not necessarily slower. Based on benchmarks I've run, and which are *somewhere* on SO, an anchored pattern can be a whole lot faster than an in-string search. It's important to run the benchmarks to test specific use-cases though, as it can all be misleading once patterns are involved, because they are so much more complex than a simple string search, especially when greediness rears its head.

Comment: And, regarding benchmarking answers, I've done a [number of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A128421+benchmark). I'd recommend using [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity), as it simplifies the work needed and presents the results in a reasonable output.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid the conversion into a byte array by using a regular expression and [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
bad_bytes_pattern = /[#{ Regexp.escape(bad_bytes.map(&:chr).join) }]/n
#=> /[\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\v\x0E\x0F\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1A\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F\x7F]/

str = File.binread('some_file')

if str[bad_bytes_pattern]
  # contains bad bytes
else
  # ...
end
```

You can simplify the regexp by using character ranges:

```
bad_bytes_pattern = /[\x00-\x06\x0B\x0E-\x1A\x1C-\x1F\x7F]/n
```

Comment: That's an interesting thought! I've always "heard" regex is expensive, but like you said, it might be offset by avoiding the byte array conversion. (It also might just be nonsense.) I'll have to run some benchmarks... if it is indeed faster, I'll mark this the right answer.

Comment: Use `/[#{ bad_bytes.map(&:chr).join }]/` instead of `Regexp.union`. A character-set will be faster than a union of separate characters.

Comment: `str[bad_bytes_pattern]` will be as effective as `str.index(bad_bytes_pattern)` and a little more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F) to see if any character exists in the `bad_bytes` list:

```
my_bytes.none? { |b| bad_bytes.include? b }
```

The advantage here is that the loop will stop when the first character matches the predicate rather than going through the whole thing.

You can further optimize this by putting `bad_bytes` in a `Set`:

```
bad_bytes = Set[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127]
```

Comment: I think this is largely I was looking for: using `Set` instead of a regular enum. At first, I was a bit perplexed on which of `my_bytes.none? { |b| bad_bytes.include? b }`, vs. `bad_bytes.none? { |b| my_bytes.include? b }`, but it turns out [they have this handled](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-intersect-3F).

Comment: This will slow as either of the two arrays increase in size.

Comment: @theTinMan since the 'bad_bytes' is a Set, 'include?' is O(1) no matter its size. My solution has complexity linear with the size of my_bytes. You see a solution with better complexity?

Comment: AH. I missed that it was in a Set. Yes, that's about as fast as it can be done.

Comment: I've gone with this approach for now, at least until I have time to fix things up (much needed), and learn/integrate Fruity.

If anyone's curious as to exactly what this is for, I have some initial code up:

https://github.com/geoff-codes/autoencode

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing two things to make this efficient:

- Read the file byte-by-byte (block-by-block in the background) until a bad character is found or the entire file is read without finding a bad character.
- Convert the array of bad bytes to a set of characters, for faster lookup.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def bad_byte?(text, bad_bytes)
  bb = Set.new(bad_bytes.map(&:chr))
  f = File.new 'test'
  f.each_char.any? { |c| bb.include?(c) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
bad_bytes = [*0..6, 11, *14..26, *28..31, 127]
  #=> [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17,  18,
  #    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127]

Read a 'good' test string from a file named `'test'`.

text = "Now is the time for all good people"
File.write('test', text)
bad_byte?(text, bad_bytes) #=> false

Read a 'bad' test string from a file named `'test'`.

text = "Now is the time " + 3.chr + "for all good people"
File.write('test', text)
bad_byte?(text, bad_bytes) #=> true
```